# Pre-proccessing steps in Machine Learning

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

Why it is so important to do pre-processing and what are the simple steps doing it? Can anyone help. I am working on python.

I have a dataframe consisting of null values. The data consist of outliers, moreover it is not distributed uniformly.

My question is what protocol I should follow inorder to fill null values, should I remove outliers because this might lead to loss of information and what are the steps to make data distributed uniformly?

Comment: There are plenty of blogs and tutorials out there that will give you a good idea of why. Also, this question is off topic for stack overflow, please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly it really doesnot matter which language you are working on. Both python and R are popular in Data Science.

Secondly, you cannot insert raw data to any machine learning models. Before you need to clean it. Here are some simple steps:

**1. Remove missing values:** Many a times there are missing values present in the data. So you have to fill those data. Question arises how? There are planty of methods which you can google out.

**2. Remove skewness and outliers:** Generally data contains values that are not within the range of other data. So you have to bring those data with that range.

**3. One-hot-encoding:** Categorical values needs to be transformed to encoding format.

Still there are more steps but you to google it out there are tons of blogs you can go through.